# Create JTree of objects and their declared fields with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jtree

I need dynamic JTree where nodes would be objects and when node is expanded i would use reflection to get the declared fields. All non - primitive fields would again be nodes, and so on, recursively.

So here is short desc of my TreeNode class:

```
 public TreeNode(Object o){

        this.name = o.getClass().getSimpleName();
        this.treeobjectclass = o.getClass();
        this.isbranch = isBranchObject();
        this.properties = initializePropertiesMap();
        this.children = //here i will get children with getDeclared fields and 
                       //instantiate new TreeNode for nonprimitive ones

}
```

Questions:

1. When doing recursive instantiation through children, how can I avoid a problem when I run into one of children classes whose constructor asks for arguments?
2. Should I maybe be passing the Class parameter instead of Object into constructor?
3. If i do this, what if later i need to get the object of this class, and i try it with class.getConstructor - again, I dont have parameters.

How to get out of this cursed loop ? Im totally new with reflection. Any examples of similar work?

Thank you

Comment: What's the motivation behind using reflection for this? Perhaps _architechture_ can solve these problems naturally for you instead.

Comment: @Johan Sjöberg: the reason for using reflection is that jtree will have checkboxes, and when checkbox on some node / leaf is clicked, field name will be used in dynamic query generation. I am sorry can you explain "architecture"?? I am not familiar with it. Thanx

Comment: What I'm trying to imply here is that you can perhaps find a solution using regular instation logic if you design your program for it, rather than using reflection.

Comment: @Johan Sjöberg: ok, excuse if im totally missing the point, but I see no other way of getting the fields of each Object/Class, and then to repeat that process recursively for each non-primitive field, without using reflection?

Comment: You say you need a field name when a checkbox is clicked? Put a getter for it, or make use of the listener pattern allowing your end-objects to communicate necessary information back to your dynamic query generator. If you need to instantiation logic, try to use the [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this doesn't look like a typical use case for reflection. Anyway, to try and answer your questions:

1. What you can do is that you enable the default constructor regardless of whether it's private or not, using `ctor.setAccessible(true)`, and instantiate it using e.g., `clazz.newInstance()`. If it is however nonexistant, you're into a guessing game of constructor parameters or into the `sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(clazz)`, neither of which is to prefer.
2. What you're using it for, it looks like it should suffice with the class reference. Passing an object would imply that it's used, which it's not really.
3. If you need to pass an object only to get it's constructor arguments, then I'd say your better of passing a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for that object to avoid reflection completely. This is also a recommendation from the Oracle [Secure Coding Guideline](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#4-0).

A modification to passing a factory would be to let each class that you wish to instantiate provide its own factory logic, e.g.,

```
interface FactoryProvider<T> {
    public T getInstance();
}

class Concrete  implements FactoryProvider<Concrete> {

    @Override
    public Concrete getInstance() {
        return new Concrete();
    }
}
```

But then again, if you have complete control of the source code of all objects created this way you can yourself enforce that they all have default constructor.

Comment: Point 1 would not work if there is no no-argument constructor. It is only auto-generated when you give no other constructors. Point 3 would not work, too, since constructors are not inherited.

Comment: If you only want to create a tree for type introspection, the `Class` objects are enough. If you want to show an existing object, then you have already your objects (don't need to create). If you want to dynamically create objects, I'm now out of ideas. I think you should explain (by editing the question) what you need your class tree for.

Comment: Ah, you are right, that only works for non-default constructors, I'll edit.